# Message Format using C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to convert a sample win form app to console application.I just stuck when am trying to convert to message format.

Here is the below original code from winform

```
private void PutMessage(StringBuilder message, string mediaType, string filename)
{

    message.AppendFormat(messageFormat, "FileSize", videoInterrogator.GetFileSize(), Environment.NewLine);
    message.AppendFormat(messageFormat, "Duration", videoInterrogator.GetDuration(), Environment.NewLine);

}
```

Am trying to do the same in my console application

Am calling the method from FTPDownload method so the code look like

```
PutMessage(file, message);


private void PutMessage(string filename, StringBuilder message)
{
    VideoInterrogator videoInterrogator = new VideoInterrogator();
    videoInterrogator.LoadFile(filename);
    message.AppendFormat(format, "FileSize", videoInterrogator.GetFileSize(), Environment.NewLine);
    message.AppendFormat(format, "Duration", videoInterrogator.GetDuration(), Environment.NewLine);

}
```

Any help please how can i call this method pass the file name and return the values.It throws exception at "Format" am not sure what am missing here.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post some more code to give more context of the Method.  Where is `format` declared, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a variable `format`. It must have been a field in your WinForms code. Either add it to the method as a local variable, or a field to the class containing `PutMessage`.

EDIT: I think I'm just not sure what the actual problem is. Is it the missing variable or does the format string have more or less than 3 curly-brace arguments?

Comment: Thanks all for the great help ,am an Idiot,haven't notice this piece in the code block  public string messageFormat
        {
            get
            {
                return "{0}: {1}{2}";
            }
        }

Comment: @Usher: properties should start with capitals, which would have made it less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it like you'd call any method:

```
var message = new StringBuilder();
var filename = "file.xyz";
PutMessage(filename, message);
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew,its throwing exception at @format,it throws format doesnt exist in the current context.

Comment: You either need to add format as another parameter to PutMessage, or make it a member of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the signature of the [AppendFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4th7yht7.aspx) method you are using, you are missing the string that is used for the formating. according to above MSDN link:

> This method uses the composite formatting feature of the .NET
> Framework to convert the value of an object to its text representation
> and embed that representation in the current StringBuilder object.
>
> The format parameter consists of zero or more runs of text intermixed
> with zero or more indexed placeholders, called format items, that
> correspond to arg0 through arg3, the objects in the parameter list of
> this method. The formatting process replaces each format item with the
> string representation of the corresponding object.   The syntax of a
> format item is as follows:
>
> {index[,length][:formatString]}
>
> Elements in square brackets are optional.